# Create stacked bar with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have data displayed in the following format:

```
values = np.array([10, 12,13, 5,20], [30, 7, 10, 25,2], [10, 12,13, 5,20]])
```

And I want to create a straight-up stacked bar chart like the following figure. Each element in the array belongs to a stacked bar.

[image]

I have searched to see how can I do this with matplotlib, but unfortunately, I still haven't found a way to do it. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate a stacked bar chart with word count and column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239435/how-to-annotate-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-word-count-and-column-name)

Comment: [Stacked Bar Chart with Centered Labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41296313) & [How to annotate a pandas stacked bar, with more than 2 stacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60875468)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is now straightforward way to do it. You need to calculate exact position of bars yourself and then normalize it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

values = np.array([[10, 12,13, 5,20], [30, 7, 10, 25,2], [10, 12,13, 5,20]])
values_normalized = values/np.sum(values, axis=0)
bottom_values = np.cumsum(values_normalized, axis=0)
bottom_values = np.vstack([np.zeros(values_normalized[0].size), bottom_values])
text_positions = (bottom_values[1:] + bottom_values[:-1])/2
r = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] # position of the bars on the x-axis
names = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'] # names of groups
colors = ['lightblue', 'orange', 'lightgreen']
for i in range(3):
    plt.bar(r, values_normalized[i], bottom=bottom_values[i], color=colors[i], edgecolor='white', width=1, tick_label=['a','b','c','d','e'])
    for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(r, text_positions[i], values[i]):
        plt.text(xpos, ypos, "N=%d"%yval, ha="center", va="center")
    # Custom X axis
plt.xticks(r, names, fontweight='bold')
plt.xlabel("group")
plt.show()
```

[There is a source](https://pythonmatplotlibtips.blogspot.com/2018/11/normalized-stacked-barplot-number-percentage-python-matplotlib.html) that tells how to add text on top of bars. I'm a bit in a hurry right now so I hope this is useful <s>and I'll update my answer next day if needed.</s>

I've updated my answer. Adding text on top of the bars is tricky, it requires some calculations of their vertical positions.

Btw, I have refactored the most of code that is in a link I shared.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Python 3.8
- matplotlib 3.3.1
- numpy 1.19.1

[Chat Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qo3y.png)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

values = np.array([[10, 12, 13, 5, 20], [30, 7, 10, 25, 2], [10, 12, 13, 5, 20]])
row, column = values.shape  # (3, 5)

x_type = [x+1 for x in range(column)]
ind = [x for x, _ in enumerate(x_type)]

values_normalized = values/np.sum(values, axis=0)
value1, value2, value3 = values_normalized[0,:], values_normalized[1,:], values_normalized[2,:]

# Create figure
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.bar(ind, value1, width=0.8, label='Searies1', color='#5B9BD5')
plt.bar(ind, value2, width=0.8, label='Searies2', color='#C00000', bottom=value1)
plt.bar(ind, value3, width=0.8, label='Searies3', color='#70AD47', bottom=value1 + value2)

# Show text
bottom_values = np.cumsum(values_normalized, axis=0)
bottom_values = np.vstack([np.zeros(values_normalized[0].size), bottom_values])
text_positions = (bottom_values[1:] + bottom_values[:-1])/2
c = list(range(column))
for i in range(3):
    for xpos, ypos, yval in zip(c, text_positions[i], values[i]):
        plt.text(xpos, ypos, yval, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', color='white')

plt.xticks(ind, x_type)
plt.legend(loc='center', bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.02, 1, 0.1), handlelength=1, handleheight=1, ncol=row)
plt.title('CHART TITLE', fontdict = {'fontsize': 16,'fontweight': 'bold', 'family': 'serif'}, y=1.1)

# Hide y-axis
plt.gca().axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```