# how to create a bar chart in python with multiple x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a dataset with 3 columns:
BOROUGHS, COMPLAINT_DATE, OFFENSE

NOTE: the date format is like this: `2010-01-30`

I do know how to create a simple bar chart...like this:

```
df.plot(kind="bar")
```

But, I need something like this:

[image]

This chart is telling me the 5 boroughs, the number of complaints and the year. Plus using colors.

First, how do you do something like that?
Second, does this type of chart has a name? like, multi-bar chart or something like that?

EDIT:
[image]

the purple color should be first...in the bar... but it says that it has more crime...

EDIT: #2
Plus...look at this number base on 2010 and 2019
[image]

Edit:#3
too small...
not showing the number of crime at the bottom
Thanks,
[image]

Comment: __the purple color should be first...in the bar... but it says that it has more crime...__ that is not how a stacked bar chart is read. Each section represents a count of offenses, only the full bar height is associated with the values on the y-axis.

Comment: This is an issue of stacked bars, it's difficult to distinguish the values in each section of the bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The data will need to be grouped and aggregated by count, and then pivoted into the correct shape.

  - Use the `.dt` accessor to extract the year from the `'complaint_date'` column.
- See [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) & [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) for all the available parameters.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
data = {'boroughs': ['x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'x'],
        'complaint_date': ['2020-11-1', '2020-11-1', '2020-11-1', '2019-11-1', '2019-11-1', '2019-11-1', '2020-11-1', '2020-11-1', '2020-11-1', '2019-11-1', '2019-11-1', '2019-11-1', '2019-11-1'],
        'offense': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'd']}

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert date column to datetime dtype
df.complaint_date = pd.to_datetime(df.complaint_date)

# groupby year and borough to get count of offenses
dfg = df.groupby([df.complaint_date.dt.year, 'boroughs']).boroughs.count().reset_index(name='count')

# display(dfg)
   complaint_date boroughs  count
0            2019        x      3
1            2019        y      2
2            2019        z      2
3            2020        x      2
4            2020        y      2
5            2020        z      2

# pivot into the correct form for stacked bar
dfp = dfg.pivot(index='complaint_date', columns='boroughs', values='count')

# display(dfp)
boroughs        x  y  z
complaint_date         
2019            3  2  2
2020            2  2  2

# plot
dfp.plot.bar(stacked=True, xlabel='Year Complaint Filed', ylabel='Volumn of Complaints')
plt.legend(title='Boroughs', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

[image]

- Use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60891753/7758804) to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60875468/7758804) to add annotations to the stacked bars.

### Response to comment

- In response to `AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'xlabel'`
- `pandas` probably needs to be updated; this was run in version `1.1.3`.

```py
# plot
dfp.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.legend(title='Boroughs', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.xlabel('Year Complaint Filed')
plt.ylabel('Volumn of Complaints')
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

### A better option than a stacked bar

- Use `seaborn.barplot`
- This will provide a better overall representation of the relative values for each bar.

```py
import seaborn as sns

# use dfg from above

# plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 4))
sns.barplot(y='complaint_date', x='count', data=dfg, hue='boroughs', orient='h', ax=ax)

# use log scale since you have large numbers
plt.xscale('log')

# relocate the legend
plt.legend(title='Boroughs', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

- See [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21920233/7758804) or [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14530113/7758804) to change the format of the x-tick values from exponents to integers.

Comment: PERFECT! THANK YOU!!! ....Thanks for your help...it works!